# Is there a way to strip out a prototype method and make it work as a function?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to make Array.prototype.map a function and call it as `customMap(passitanyarray,function)`

In general,
is there a way to get `Array.prototype.(whatever)` and take whatever and make it your own function. 
for example like
`Array.prototype.map(function())`

and extract map and use like this `map([],function())` instead of `Array.prototype.map(function())`

I would explain more if that is not clear.

Thanks,
In advance

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill

Comment: `[].map.call([], function () { ... });` should do the trick. While the second [] is your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the `arr.map()` invocation like this:

```js
function map(arr, fn) {
  return arr.map(fn);
}

console.log(map([1,2,3], x => x + 1));
```

Comment: How about the Polyfill can't I make it accept an array ?

Comment: @JS Lover, the polyfill simply defines `the Array.prototype.map()` function if it is not defined, so this code will still work since it will call this specific implementation in that case.

Comment: I meant can't I modify that code and make it accept a function. Instead of attaching that to the prototype.

Comment: @JS Lover, I do not understand, Array.prototype.map is already taking a function. The polyfill does not accept a function either, it simply implements Array.prototype.map if it is not defined

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't. You are correct. I was looking for a way to modify it because that what I was thinking to do when I wrote the question. But your answer work. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to manage the correct context of `this` with the function you *could* extract the `call()` function and provide it with the correct context. It's a little ugly (and I'm not sure it's wise), but it works and should work even with the polyfill:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3]

/* get reference to properly bound call() */
let map = Function.call.bind(Array.prototype.map)

/* now you can use it like a regular function */
let double = map(arr, item => item * 2)
console.log(double)
```